# add installation prefix of rrt_ros to cmake_prefix_path

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to add installation prefix of rrt_ros to cmake_prefix_path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254373/add-installation-prefix-of-rrt_ros-to-cmake_prefix_path/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since we have used `catkin_make_isolated --instal`l during building the orocos_toolchain if u want to use  the `rrt_ros with ur catkin package` u have to build ur package `inside the ws workspace only` where u build the orocos_ros package and rtt_ros package.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2017-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0